# Mudar a classe de acordo com a condição

Tags: jquery

Gostaria de fazer duas coisas:

- Um que o `label` com id `cnt`, quando apertasse o botão mais, somasse mais 1 e quando apertasse o botão menos, subtrai-se menos 1.
- Fora isso, quando o `label` `cnt` fosse igual a zero, retirasse a classe `pizzaselecionada`.

Fazer a classe mudar se o `label=#cnt` for igual a `0`

```
<script>

   $(document).ready(function(e) {

        var Total = parseFloat('0');

        var P = $('.pizzadisponivel label').attr('value');

        var Pp = (P.replace(/,/,'.'));

        var cn = parseFloat('0');

    $('#mais').click(function(e) {
        $('li').hasClass('pizzadisponivel');
        $('li').removeClass('pizzadisponivel');
        $('li').addClass('pizzaselecionada');

        Total += parseFloat(Pp);
        $("#teste").html('R$' + parseFloat(Total).toFixed(2));
        alert(Total)

});

    $('#menos').click(function(e) {
        if ($('label #cnt').){ 
            $('li').hasClass('pizzaselecionada');
            $('li').removeClass('pizzaselecionada');
            $('li').addClass('pizzadisponivel');
        }

      else  {Total -= parseFloat(Pp);
            $("#teste").html('R$' + parseFloat(Total).toFixed(2));
            alert(Total);
        }
});

});


</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <li class="pizzadisponivel"><label value="29,90">29,90</label></li>
        <button id="mais">mais</button>
        <button id="menos">menos</button>
        <label id="cnt">0</label>
        <label id="teste">R$0,00</label>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Amigo, sabemos que você deseja alguma(s) coisa(s). Tente indicar no título o que você deseja. Não encare isso como uma crítica negativa... mas assim funciona o *SOpt*.

Comment: Tudo bem, muito obrigado, vou coloca certinho no título

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que seja isto que esteja querendo fazer, lembrando que neste cenário apenas vai funcionar para 1 pizza para mais pizzas deveria mudar totalmente a programação.

```js
   $(document).ready(function(e) {
     var mais = $("#maois"),
       menos = $("#menos"),
       qtd = $("#qtd"),
       total = $("#total"),
       pizza = $('.pizzadisponivel'),
       valuePizza = $(".pizzadisponivel > label").attr('value').replace(/,/, '.');


     $('#mais').click(function(e) {
       var novaQtd = parseInt(qtd.text()) + 1;
       total.text("R$ " + (novaQtd * valuePizza).toFixed(2));
       pizza.addClass("pizzaselecionada");
       pizza.removeClass('pizzadisponivel');

       qtd.text(novaQtd);

     });

     $('#menos').click(function(e) {
       if (parseInt(qtd.text()) > 0) {         
         var novaQtd = parseInt(qtd.text()) - 1;
         qtd.text(novaQtd);
         total.text("R$ " + (novaQtd * valuePizza).toFixed(2))
         if(novaQtd == 0){
           pizza.removeClass("pizzaselecionada");
           pizza.addClass("pizzadisponivel");

           }
       }
     });

   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <div>
    <li class="pizzadisponivel">
      <label value="29,90">Calabresa 29,90</label>
    </li>
    <button id="mais">mais</button>
    <button id="menos">menos</button>
    <label id="qtd">0</label>
    <label id="total">R$0,00</label>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```